# C# | Invalid Resx file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I recently started coding C# windows forms (.NET framework) in Visual Studio 2022. I am getting this error `Invalid Resx file. Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20.` I am getting this error for each of my form (8 forms). And when I open any of the resource file, I get around 700 other errors from the same file.

Attaching the screenshot of errors as well as code :

This is the first error
[image: This is the first error]

And this is the code in the resx file (from the 1st line)
[image: And this is the code in the resx file (from the 1st line)]

Sorry if I used any wrong terms and Thank you in advance.

Comment: resx is an XML format, but the file you show us is no valid XML. Did you edit these files with any other tool?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite explicit, you have an error at line 1, position 3.

In order to solve the problem you should delete the space after the `<`

It should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but not `<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.